# widcomm stack - How to use it?

Tags: windows-mobile, bluetooth, broadcom

I am trying to work out an application for Windows Mobile 6 that uses Widcomm Bluetooth for searching for devices and opens a com (with spp service).

I put `inthehand.net.personal.dll` and `32feetWidcomm.dll` in the application folder, but when I debug I always get a missing method exception from `BluetoothFactoryConfig.KnownStacks` in bluetoothfactory.

Can please someone tell me what to declare in my app or if I'm using the wrong dll?

Comment: Might be best to post a question at our forums at http://inthehand.co.uk/forums/37.aspx  Can you show me the MMEx including its stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the `inthehand.net.personal.dll` are you using? They have just released v2.5 two days ago, so maybe `KnownStacks` is a new feature in the latest version? You can find v2.5 [here](http://32feet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=27693).